# Merge two cells in excel

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x

I have two columns in excel

Column A:

[image]

and Column B:

[image]

How can I merge these two columns such that I have an output like this:
It's better that I do this in excel itself but pandas works too.
Column C:

**[image: strong text]**

Comment: What happened to 111 and 112?

Comment: @SolarMike I don' want 111 and 112, I just want to fill only blank columns of A with columns of B

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In column C, insert:

```
=IF(A1="",B1,A1)
```

Comment: why use ";" instead of ","

Comment: Edited, thanks. My french version of excel uses semi-colons in its syntax instead of commas.

Comment: @MEdwin That is normal for excel depending on the country and choices made during the install process. Most on here will not worry about the difference and write or rewrite answers as needed after testing.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a pandas solution

```
import pandas as pd

df_b = pd.DataFrame({'col':[1,2,np.NaN,4,5,np.NaN,np.NaN,8,9,10]})
df_c = pd.DataFrame({'col':[111,112,113,114,115,116,117,118,119,110]})

>>>df_b.combine_first(df_c)
     col
0    1.0
1    2.0
2  113.0
3    4.0
4    5.0
5  116.0
6  117.0
7    8.0
8    9.0
9   10.0
```

**Note** Please pay close attention to the column labels that I used in my setup. It is necessary for the `combine_first()` function to work automatically.

Comment: But what if they both are just two columns in a dataframe rather than two seprate df?

Comment: @RahulSharma In that case, you can construct a new column for the dataframe by using list comprehension. In your example, it would be `df['C'] = [y if pd.isnull(x) else x for x,y in zip(df.loc[:,'A'], df.loc[:,'B'])]`

Answer (score 1):

I will do a version for pandas, just in case someone will want everything done in python.
The technique is bfill.
The code below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A':[1,2,None,4,5,None,None,8,9,10],
    'B':[111,112,113,114,115,116,117,118,119,110]
                  })
df['D'] = df.bfill(axis=1).iloc[:,0]
df
```

result below:

```
    A   B   D
0   1.0 111 1.0
1   2.0 112 2.0
2   NaN 113 113.0
3   4.0 114 4.0
4   5.0 115 5.0
5   NaN 116 116.0
6   NaN 117 117.0
7   8.0 118 8.0
8   9.0 119 9.0
9   10.0    110 10.0
```

Comment: what's a bfill?

Comment: @RahulSharma, bfill is for next valid observation filling: it allows you to populate or fill the gap by adopting a non NaN value. Exactly what the excel function IF(A1="",B1,A1) does.

Answer (score 0):

So try this:

```
=IFERROR(IF(A1="",B1,A1),"error")
```

The iferror will deal with some possible errors.